# Apache poi "формат или расширение являются файла недопустимыми"

Tags: java, apache-poi

Генерирую xlsx с помощью apache poi, использую последнюю версию

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

public String generateXlsx(List<Section> sections, int idJob) throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook ExcelBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        filename = "filestorage/workbook"+idJob+".xlsx";
        File file = new File(filename);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = ExcelBook.createSheet();
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);

        cell.setCellValue("Section Name");
        for(int i = 1; i <= getMaxLength(sections)*2; i++)
            row.createCell(i)
                    .setCellValue( i % 2 == 1 ?
                    "class " + i % 2 + i / 2 + " name" :
                    "class " + i % 2 + i / 2 + " code");

        short rowNum = 1;
        for (Section section : sections) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(section.getName());
            int cellNum = 1;
            for (GeologicalClass geologicalClass : section.getGeologicalClasses()) {
                cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
                cell.setCellValue(geologicalClass.getName());
                cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
                cell.setCellValue(geologicalClass.getCode());
            }
        }

        ExcelBook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        return filename;
    }
```

Файл создается, что то в него пишется, размер ненулевой. При попытке открыть в Excel 2013 пишет неверный формат или файл поврежден. В чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 0):

Для поддержки xlsx формата Excel 2007+ нужно добавить библиотеку

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Соответственно генерация файла

```
public String generateXlsx(List<Section> sections, int idJob) throws IOException {
    Workbook ExcelBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = ExcelBook.createSheet();
    Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    Font font = ExcelBook.createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    CellStyle style = ExcelBook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell.setCellValue("Section Name");

    int columnNum = getMaxLength(sections)*2;
    for(int i = 1; i <= columnNum; i++) {
        cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(i % 2 == 1 ?
                        "class " + i % 2 + i / 2 + " name" :
                        "class " + i % 2 + i / 2 + " code");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
    short rowNum = 1;
    for (Section section : sections) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(section.getName());
        int cellNum = 1;
        for (GeologicalClass geologicalClass : section.getGeologicalClasses()) {
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(geologicalClass.getName());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(geologicalClass.getCode());
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= columnNum; i++){
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

    PropertyTemplate propertyTemplate=new PropertyTemplate();
    propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,columnNum),
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM,BorderExtent.ALL);
    propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(0,sections.size(),0,0),
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM,BorderExtent.ALL);
    propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(0,sections.size(),0,columnNum),
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM,BorderExtent.BOTTOM);
    propertyTemplate.applyBorders(sheet);

    filename = "filestorage/workbook"+idJob+".xlsx";
    File file = new File(filename);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ExcelBook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    ExcelBook.close();
    return filename;
}
```